# Google Places - Script - Opening hours function not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-places-api

I'm using a script based on the Google Places API to get the opening hours of a place displayed on Google.

Here is my code:

```
      function hor(place, city, state) {
      var API_KEY = 'xxx';
      var url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' +
      place + ' ' + city + ' ' + state + '&key=' + API_KEY;
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
      var json = response.getContentText();
      obj = JSON.parse(json);
      hours = obj.results[0].opening_hours;
      return hours;
```

When i'm running the ggsheet function "horaires", the following mistake appears:

*TypeError: Cannot read property "opening_hours" from undefined.*

Do you know what is causing the mistake ?

Thanks a lot for your help,
Tim

documentation: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details

Comment: Where are you using the "opening_hours" property ?

Comment: Sorry, I had the wrong version. Just edited it

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation the object returned has a key named `result` not in in plural, it is also an object and not an array as you are trying to access in your code.

The call should be

```
hours = obj.result.opening_hours;
```

Do note that to get the individual hours you would have to be more specific. `opening_hours` is an object with fields. To get the opening hours of the first day of the week you'd have to do

```
hours = obj.result.opening_hours.periods[0].open.time
```

This will return the time when the store opens on a Sunday.

Comment: Hi, I unfortunately have the same issue 'TypeError: Cannot read property "opening_hours" from undefined. (line 84).'

Comment: Are you sure that the URL is correct? what do you get if you log the response?